# Width: 100% is not applied to child box properly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

## Background

I made a simple card layout.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}
.card > .img-window {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/169950/photo-1470020337050-543c4e581988.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.card > .content {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(82, 113, 121);
}
```

```html
<div class='card'>
  <div class='img-window'></div>
  <div class='content'>
    <h1>Main Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Problem

```
.card > .img-window {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I applied `width: 100%` but it is not working as I expected. The `.img-window` box probably takes only about 40% of full width.

1. Why isn't it 100%?
2. What calculation is applied to `.img-window` box? How does the browser calculate the 100% in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are missing `flex-wrap`. Even if you set image `width` to `100%`, your flex child will shrink to fit, because you don't tell its parent to `wrap`. Take a look at CSS trick article: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/

Here is my code with `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `.card`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.card > .img-window {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/169950/photo-1470020337050-543c4e581988.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.card > .content {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(82, 113, 121);
}
```

```html
<div class='card'>
  <div class='img-window'></div>
  <div class='content'>
    <h1>Main Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit:

It's is 100%, but its parent flex direction is `row`, and didn't tell childs to wrap when overflow. That's why you need flex-wrap.

Comment: Oh yea, thank you. I edited my question. Check please !

Comment: @ByeonginYoon I have edited my answer with explain at bottom. Hope this will help\

Comment: yap, What I am curious is how 100% is calculated in this situation by the browser. Why does browser calculate 100% to 278px ?

Comment: @ByeonginYoon let take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/3eqptdLm/, when I set text in `.content` to a single word, the child-flex in right shrink to small and `.img-window` grow to fit the whole row. Then I extend the paragraph in content: https://jsfiddle.net/5whmy9gx/1, the right flex-child grow up and `.img-window` shrink to fit. This mean width of your image is depend on the other flex-child (in your case it's `.content`).

Comment: The image size is depend on the other flex-child ! Thank you :D.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, the problem is with closing of your Div tag, You are opening and closing it on same line.

Notice this

```
<div class='img-window'></div>
```

This should probably fix it

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}
.card > .img-window {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/169950/photo-1470020337050-543c4e581988.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.card > .content {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(82, 113, 121);
}
```

```html
<div class='card'>
  <div class='img-window'>
  <div class='content'>
    <h1>Main Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div class='img-window'></div>` was intended.